# Is it possible to start a substrate BABE blockchain with no Grandpa authorities and BABE validators?

Tags: staking, validator, grandpa, babe, session

I'm trying to implement a PoS network on substrate using substrate provided pallets - `pallet_session`, `pallet_staking`, `pallet_babe`, etc. The current Runtime and chain spec implementation is similar to what is found in the [substrate repository](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/bin/node).
I've realized that I need to set Session keys for `GenesisConfig` before starting the blockchain. I also noticed that the Session keys set for `SessionConfig` are used to configure the grandpa authorities.

My questions are:

Is there a way to start the blockchain such that no session keys are set?

Do all `grandpa` authorities need to be hardcoded in the chain spec? If not, how are the authorities added ***after*** nodes have gone live?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to start the blockchain such that no session keys are set?

No, then no one could produce blocks nor finalize blocks.

> Do all grandpa authorities need to be hardcoded in the chain spec? If not, how are the authorities added after nodes have gone live?

All initial validators need to have set all session keys which includes the grandpa keys. After the chain is running new authorities will then be able to join by staking funds and being elected into the active set.

Comment: Would it be possible to reach a parity developer to ask further questions?

Comment: Further questions about what? You can always open an issue on github.

Comment: Further questions on how to modify substrate so the initial validators aren't required. Perhaps a guideline

Comment: That is not possible. You need at genesis validators. How would you otherwise want to produce blocks etc. I think you are putting too much thinking into something that isn't really any problem.

Comment: i am also stuck in the same problem. i have added the pallet_session in running solo chain and now want to configure this OnRuntimeUpgrade to add initial authorities but unable to do so. please need some guidence